# concatenating same named files in two folders into one

Tags: bash, unix

i have two folders containing some thousands of documents. Say A and B are directories.Both `A` and `B` contains files `a.x b.x` and so on. There content are different of course. So i would like to append `a.x & a.x`  to generate another `a.x` in some other folder. Moreover I need to  remove fist token from second document like:

```
a.x in A:1 i go home
a.x in B:1 he goes home
```

I want to generate new document as:

```
      1 i go home  he goes home.
```

Please suggest me some scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
mkdir OUTPUT
cd A
for f in *
do
  join $f ../B/$f > ../OUTPUT/$f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a `for ... in` loop and `join(1)`:

```
mkdir c # for storing the results
for file in $(ls a): do
    join "a/$file" "b/$file" >> "c/$file"
done
```

Comment: does it remove the first token of second file?

Comment: Use a glob instead of iterating over the output of `ls`.

Comment: i want to remove first token of second file too

Comment: @chepner: Sure, but then I'd had to resolve the `b` directory. If you like that, use @StephaneRouberol's answer. @thetna: Did you even try it out?

Comment: Your answer fails for files whose names contain a space; otherwise, this does nothing differently than Stephane's answer.

Comment: It doesn't handle spaces, correct. Updated to fix that, thanks! OTOH, neither does Stephane's answer. And boy, they are strikingly similar! We also posted at the same time, so what do you do? Well, argue on the Internet of course. Cheers!